# Java serialization, android

Tags: java, android

I need to save data into object

Here is my object class where I must store data:

```
public static class FilterEntity implements Serializable {
    public int ageFrom;
    public int ageTo;
    public String sex;
    public String status;


    public void setAgeFrom()
    {
        this.ageFrom = ageFrom;
    }

    public void setAgeTo()
    {
        this.ageTo = ageTo;
    }

    public void setSex()
    {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public void setStatus()
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getAgeFrom()
    {

        return ageFrom;
    }

    public Integer getAgeTo()
    {
        return ageTo;
    }

    public String getSex()
    {
        return sex;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }



}
```

Is it correct implementation of serialization?

In the main activity I'm saving data to FilterEntity object

```
private FilterEntity filter = new FilterEntity();    
filter.status = valueOf(spStatusForSearch.toString());
filter.sex = valueOf(rgSex);
filter.ageTo = sbAgeHigh.getProgress();
filter.ageFrom = sbAgeLow.getProgress();
```

Can I do it such way?

How I can get access to data, from the third class?

Comment: Your implementation is correct. Read this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use static

```
public class FilterEntity implements Serializable {
public int ageFrom;
public int ageTo;
public String sex;
public String status;


public void setAgeFrom()
{
    this.ageFrom = ageFrom;
}

public void setAgeTo()
{
    this.ageTo = ageTo;
}

public void setSex()
{
    this.sex = sex;
}

public void setStatus()
{
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getAgeFrom()
{

    return ageFrom;
}

public Integer getAgeTo()
{
    return ageTo;
}

public String getSex()
{
    return sex;
}

public String getStatus()
{
    return status;
}
}
```

To set Values to Model Class

```
FilterEntity filter = new FilterEntity();
filter.setStatus(spStatusForSearch.toString());
filter.setSex(rgSex);
filter.setAgeTo(sbAgeHigh.getProgress());
filter.setAgeFrom(sbAgeLow.getProgress());
```

And to get Values

```
String status = filter.getStatus();
String sex = filter.getSex();
String ageTo = filter.getAgeTo();
String ageFrom = filter.getAgeFrom();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  class FilterEntity 
{
    public int ageFrom;
    public int ageTo;
    public String sex;
    public String status;
    public FilterEntity(int ageFrom, int ageTo, String sex,String status) 
    {

        this.ageFrom = ageFrom;
        this.ageTo = ageTo;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public int getAgeFrom()
    {

        return ageFrom;
    }
    public int getAgeTo()
    {
        return ageTo;
    }
    public String getSex()
    {
        return sex;
    }
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

}

// in your main activity file where your are saving the data

static ArrayList<FilterEntity> data=new ArrayList<FilterEntity>();

data.add(new FilterEntity(sbAgeLow.getProgress(),sbAgeHigh.getProgress(),valueOf(rgSex),valueOf(spStatusForSearch.toString())));

// you can add multiple like this


/*Now pass this arraylist to your third activity through intent or make this arraylist static so will be able to access this arraylist anywhere through the name of the class example: MainActivity.data*/


//Now in the third activity where you want the data of the object , get the arraylist


ArrayList data=MainActivity.data;
Iterator iterotor=data.iterator();
while (iterotor.hasNext())
{
    FilterEntity filterEntity=iterotor.next();
    // the multiple values you add

    String status = filterEntity.getStatus();
    String sex = filterEntity.getSex();
    int ageTo = filterEntity.getAgeTo();
    int ageFrom = filterEntity.getAgeFrom();

}
```